# Can't find a button with FindWindowEx

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm using `FindWindow()` and `FindWindowEx()` to control an application. There are 2 buttons in the application, one named "I Agree" and the second "Cancel". I can find the "Cancel" button but can't find the "I Agree" button.

I'm using `FindWindow()` to find the application, and I store the window's process in the `hwnd` variable.
Then I do this to find and get a button:

```
hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Cancel");
```

Why can't I find the "I Agree" button, but I can find the "Cancel" button?.

[image: The Buttons in the application.]

Comment: try the following: hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", null);

Comment: If you're wanting to control another application, have you considered using something like UI Automation which lets you work at a *higher level* than fiddling around with raw windows, etc?

Comment: That *"higher level"* also allows you to automate applications, that do not use controls backed by native windows. Very common with web browsers. Or WPF and UWP applications.

Comment: Use a tool like Spy++/Inspect to capture the window details..like window name and class correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "I Agree" button is actually "I &Agree". [Check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860155/why-doesnt-findwindowex-find-all-my-buttons) to find out why.
Thanks!